# Как сделать цикл While по тикам

Tags: c#, unity3d

метод Update в c# выполняет определённый ряд действий каждый кадр. Предроложим, что я хочу сделать медленное увеличение предмета. Изначальный его размер - 20 по x и 20 по y, я же хочу, чтобы эти переменные плавно перешли из двадцати к тридцати. В таком случае я пишу, что float scale = 20 (Там, где объявляются переменные), а scale++; кидаю в while. Но в вайле всё обрабатывается мгновенно, и как только скрипт запускается, scale для предмета уже равен 30. Как мне сделать плавное увеличение и так, чтобы while выполнялся не со скоростью вычисления компьютера, а по тикам, как в update?

Comment: Подойдет обычный таймер или анимацией можно сделать

Comment: `scale += 1*Time.DeltaTime`
Или же почитайте за timeScale в Unity(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)

Comment: И не советую кидать while в Update, подойдёт простая проверка через if-else

Answer (score 1):

While тут вообще не причём. Это можно сделать через корутину с IEnumerator функцией, которую ты видимо увидел, но это не история про анимацию с течении времени. То, что ты увидел это просто пример, корутина для другого.

Изучи каждую строчку, разберись и запомни, как отче наш! Спрашивай если не понятно. Действия в течении времени это очень частая хрень.

```
void Start () {
    gameObject.AddComponent<ScaleAction>().Setup(20f, 30f, 3f);
}
...
public class ScaleAction : MonoBehaviour {
    float ScaleTimer;
    float ScaleTime;
    float ScaleFrom;
    float ScaleTo;

    public void Setup (float from, float to, float time) {
        ScaleTimer = 0;
        ScaleTime = time;
        ScaleFrom = from;
        ScaleTo = to;
        SetScale(ScaleFrom);
    }

    void Update () {
        ScaleTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        float Way = ScaleTimer/ScaleTime; // Way 0 -> 1
        if (Way < 1) {
            SetScale(ScaleFrom+(ScaleTo-ScaleFrom)*Way);
        } else {
            SetScale(ScaleTo);
            Destroy(this); // Destroy ScaleAction 
        }
    }

    void SetScale (float scaleValue) {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleValue, scaleValue, scaleValue);
    }
}
```