# Узнать на сколько нужно сместить после скейла объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
Transform Transform = Transforms();
for (int i = 0; i < Transform.childCount; ++i) {
    Transform Obj = Transform.GetChild(i);
    Obj.localScale *= 1.5f;
}
```

Когда я увеличиваю объекты, они тонут в тиррейне и сдвигаются.
Ну это в принципе логично, увеличивается и места занимает больше.
На самом деле, при увеличении, `position` не меняется, но как же мне узнать, чтобы автоматом рассчитывало, после увеличения или уменьшения объектов, чтобы они не тонули и выравнивались?

Comment: Они тонут потому, что при скейле часть обьекта оказывается под терейном. Если скейлить не единовременно, а скажем в течении 0.5 секунды, всё будет ок. Расчитать приподнимание при геометрически сложной модели и не ровной поверхности пола затруднительная.

Comment: @Yaroslav, Я конечно очень рад, что вы хотите мне помочь, но я не могу никак понять,что нужно сделать, как даже код выглядеть будет, не представляю, пытаюсь как -то, что-то найти, но пока без вариантов. Область ровная без ям, бугров и прочего. Может я, что-то упускаю? Это не исключено.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061889/Как-сделать-цикл-while-по-тикам/1061964#1061964

Comment: @Yaroslav каким образом плавное изменение скейла поправит эту проблему?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, есть какие-то мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker либо волшебным, либо никаким. Одно из двух =D

Comment: @FixiDens есть, позже напишу решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-хорошему, эта проблема должна решаться на уровне создания полигональной сетки. Любой объект имеет так называемый pivot point, относительно которого и позиционируются вершины полигонов. В том числе с помощью этой точки объекты масштабируются с помощью scale'а.

---

**Данное решение подходит только для объектов с pivot'ом в центре**

Но, допустим, нам нужно решить это именно в коде. Все просто - нужно использовать AABB и немного математики:

Любой объект имеет Axis Aligned Bounding Box - данный объект гарантированно вписан в этот прямоугольник. Это очень грубое приближение, однако, в данной задаче это приближение никакого влияния на конечный результат не окажет.

Из этого AABB можно получить высоту объекта, вернее половину его высоты:

```
float objectExtent = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds.extents.y;
```

И на этом все решение и заканчивается, ведь увеличение объекта в n раз перемешает его центральную точку на `(высота * n) / 2`.

```
Transform parent = Transforms();
for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; ++i) {
    var _transform = parent.GetChild(i);
    var extentY = _transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds.extents.y;

    var pos = _transform.position;
    var scale = _transform.localScale;

    pos.y -= extentY * scale.y;

    scale *= 1.5f;
    _transform.localScale = scale;

    pos.y += extentY * scale.y;
    _transform.position = pos;
}
```

---

Очевидно, что вызывать `GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds.extents.y` каждый раз - медленно. AABB у `MeshFilter` всегда одинаковый, вне зависимости от текущего scale'а, поэтому это значение можно закешировать и переиспользовать.

Comment: А что если нет не `MeshFilter`, не `MeshRenderer`, тогда, как быть?

Comment: @FixiDens т.е. у вас вообще нет полигональной сетки, "высота" такого объекта - 0, полувысота - тоже 0. Формула от этого не поменяется. Просто значение `extentY = 0` и все.

Comment: Суть такая есть самая верхняя группа и в ней части уже с сеткой. Я хотел тупо группу увеличивать. Но что-то не получается, а когда я делаю на части то они увеличиваются и разъезжаются.

Comment: @FixiDens это абсолютно другая ситуация, о которой следует изначально писать в вопросе. Это уже так просто не решить, советую использовать решение через pivot point.

Comment: То есть? нельзя как-то на группу, что-то повешать, чтобы отследить? Я не пойму, что за `pivot point` ? Все пивоты в центре находятся.

Comment: Я кратко написал в ответе, что за pivot point. Вручную из скрипта нужно для каждого дочернего объекта выполнить логику из кода в ответе, что не очень оптимизированно.